# I want to create one common login table for different tables like Patient , Doctors, receptionist but not sure how to do it

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, database-design

I am using ASP.net MVC.
my question is that I have 2 tables patient and doctors and I want to create one common Userlogin table for both this table. So when I store username and password in UserLogin table it can determine whether it is Patient username or password or Doctor.

Can anyone please help me what should do? And give me some more idea about how and what I should change.

[image: This is my table diagram]

Comment: Not sure what your asking at all here. What does the image (which I'm guessing is your Patient and Doctors table) have to do with Login and Profiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step-1. Create RoleMaster Table and add patient , doctors , receptionist as roleName in rolemaster table.

`ColumnName Datatype
 RoleId      int
 RoleName   nvarchar(50)

 Status     bit 
 IsDeleted  bit 
CreatedDate datetime`

step-2 Add RoleId As Reference in userLogin table and profileTable.

Comment: Thanks ,I will do what you said. It make sense now.

Answer (score 2):

Doctors and patients are both subclasses of a more generic class, Users.  You may want to research a topic called "Class Table Inheritance"  There is a tag with that name here in Stackoverflow, and there are many articles on this topic on the web.

Class Table Inheritance is one way of making up for the fact that the relational model does not have a built in mechanism for inheritance.

Briefly, Your userlogin table needs a primary key, and username may not be suitable for this purpose.  Call this key, UserId.  Doctors and Patients do not need a unique id of their own.  Instead, you can include UserId in both the doctor table and the patient table.  This column should be the primary key of the doctor and patient table.  In addition, this field should be named as a foreign key that references UserID in the UserLogin table.

The UserLogin table should probably include columns (fields) for all the features that are common to both doctors and patients,  such as first name, last name, etc.

When you want to know if a user is a doctor or not,  just join UserLogin and Doctor.  Non doctors will drop out of the join.